# Where can I find out more about Aura-NG (Lightning Components combined with Angular.js library)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I heard about this at DF14 and wanted to know more!

Comment: Hey Doug, Can you edit this so that it's actually a question, and then post the answer as an answer? Answering your own question is perfectly legit on SFSE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've just opened up access to the [aura-ng github repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura-ng) and published a corresponding managed package on AppExchange. Please see the README for more details.